# Using sed to mass rename files according to contents in those files?

Tags: awk, sed

I have a bunch of files which all contain the pattern `SIZE1=%d`. Is there a way to find that decimal and prefix each filename with `%d_`?

Further if each of the files contain `SIZE1=%d` and `SIZE2=%e` can I somehow prefix each filename with `%d_%e_`?

I am trying to get a feel for how much I can do with `sed` as I have little experience with it.

Edit: For example I have a file `test_result.log`. Somewhere in that file are separate lines `SIZE1=100` and `SIZE2=150`. I want to rename the file `100_150_test_result.log`.

Comment: Colud you give a few examples with real data, both in the case where the file contains only `SIZE` and in the case it contains either `SIZE1` or `SIZE2` or both, and all three?

Comment: For example I have a file test_result.log, somewhere in that file is SIZE1=100, SIZE2=150. I want to rename the file 100_150_test_result.log

Comment: My question was more about what would happen if there is e.g. `SIZE` and `SIZE2` in the file (no `SIZE1`).  Also, what would happen if there was several copies of `SIZE` in the file?

Comment: @Kusalananda I edited my question with more correct information, there is no SIZE I was using it as a (confusing) example. Each file will either contain a single instance of SIZE1 or single instances of both SIZE1 and SIZE2. I have guaranteed this.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed you should be able to do this with a two-stage sed invocation.  First generate some test data:

```bsh
for i in {1..10}; do 
  if (( RANDOM%2 )); then 
    echo SIZE1=$((RANDOM%10)) > test$i.log
  else 
    echo SIZE1=$((RANDOM%10)) SIZE2=$((RANDOM%10)) > test$i.log
  fi
done
```

Check generated data:

```
head test*
```

Output:

```
==> test10.log <==
SIZE1=7

==> test1.log <==
SIZE1=5

==> test2.log <==
SIZE1=4 SIZE2=1

==> test3.log <==
SIZE1=9

==> test4.log <==
SIZE1=9 SIZE2=8

==> test5.log <==
SIZE1=6

==> test6.log <==
SIZE1=6

==> test7.log <==
SIZE1=5

==> test8.log <==
SIZE1=4 SIZE2=3

==> test9.log <==
SIZE1=3 SIZE2=8
```

In order to find all files with `SIZE1` and `SIZE2` first, we use a short-circuit pattern, i.e. branch (`b`) to the next file after a successful match:

*extract-params.sed*

```
/.*SIZE1=([0-9]+).*SIZE2=([0-9]+).*/ { F; s//\n\1_\2_\n/; p; b; }
/.*SIZE2=([0-9]+).*SIZE1=([0-9]+).*/ { F; s//\n\2_\1_\n/; p; b; }
/.*SIZE1=([0-9]+).*/                 { F; s//\n\1_\n/;    p; b; }
```

Once we have both the parameters and the filename, we construct the desired commands:

*create-cmds.sed*

```
N
s/([^\n]*)\n(.*)$/mv \1 \2\1/
```

Run it like this:

```
sed -znsEf extract-params.sed test* | sed -Ef create-cmds.sed
```

Output:

```
mv test1.log 5_test1.log
mv test2.log 4_1_test2.log
mv test3.log 9_test3.log
mv test4.log 9_8_test4.log
mv test5.log 6_test5.log
mv test6.log 6_test6.log
mv test7.log 5_test7.log
mv test8.log 4_3_test8.log
mv test9.log 3_8_test9.log
mv test10.log 7_test10.log
```

This can now be piped into a shell, alternatively you could use GNU sed's `/e` pattern modifier.

Comment: What is -z option? i'm getting sed: invalid option -- 'z'

Comment: @squarebase — `man sed` shows that `-z` (or `--null-data`) means, "separate lines by NUL characters". I wonder if you have an older version of `sed`? Run `sed --version`; mine is version 4.7.

Comment: @Thor — Every time I learn something new about `sed`, I am amazed at its abilities. The sed manual doesn't explain some of these terms, e.g. `F`, so I didn't know that they existed. I'm now on a mission to learn more. I've found some information on the net. Would you happen to have a link to a great sed tutorial?

Comment: Ah ok, i'm running 4.2.1. My version doesn't seem to like F either.

Comment: @PaddyLandau: There are 2 resources I would highlight [greymoire](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) and the [GNU sed manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html). Depending on your installation the manual should also be available with `info sed`

Comment: @Thor — Brilliant, thanks! The website looks more readable than `info sed`.

Comment: @paddylandau: section 7 of the manual has several interesting and we'll commented examples

Comment: Thanks, @Thor. The grymoire one had some dead links and I struggled with it, so I instead started going through the GNU sed manual from the beginning. I hadn't realised just how powerful sed was, and I'm gobsmacked that someone [wrote a chess program](https://github.com/bolknote/SedChess) in sed!